# How to enable encryption at rest in AZure AKS with terraform

Tags: azure, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

As per my understanding by default AKS dont provide Encryption at rest for OS disk and data disk. i am unable to find any reference in terraform Azure provider for same.
Please let me know if i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain its not supported (if you are talking about azure disk encryption), but everything is already encrypted at rest so unless you want to encrypt it from Microsoft - you dont have to do it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption